# SSL renewing for multi server sharepoint farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, ssl

I have a multi server sharepoint farm (2 apps, 2 wfe, 1 search/crawl, 2 dbs). It's time to renew the ssl certs for 3 web applications (not central admin). Do I need to just 1 CSR from any sharepoint server or from all sharepoint servers or create 2 separate CSR from 2 WFE Servers?

Same question when I get the cert from vendor. Do I just apply them to WFE iis at the web application level? Or all SP servers?

Can someone please help me or point me to a good article or video?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would check, what is current setup? Are we using wild card cert(1 cert for all web app) or using one cert with urls of all web application or dedicated cert for each web app?

   If it is wild card cert then create the csr on any web server after getting back cert, complete the request on same server. Once cert imported then you can export from this web server and import it to 2nd web server. After that update the Iis bindings with renewed cert.

But if it is dedicated cert for each web app then you have to create 3 csr from any web server and after getting cert,complete the cert process on same server...Now export it to 2nd server....update iis bindings with new cert on both servers.

You only need to update it on web front servers as these are the one who using it.

In rare case you have to do IISreset.